# How to reference two structures in C properly?

Tags: c, pointers, reference, structure

I have a structure defined as:

```
typedef struct{
       int pages;
    }book;
```

I first declare an instance:

```
book *b=malloc(sizeof(book));
b->pages=35;
```

Then I declare another book pointer as:

```
book *a;
a=&b;
```

After debugging I see that the member in structure `a` doesn't resemble `b`? I get false value for `pages` in `a`.

Isn't supposed that `a` points to the memory of `b`? How can I dereference `a` properly? Sorry if I have not understood the concept of pointers right.

Comment: What's the type of `&b`? Did you compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and get a warning free build?

Comment: `a` type is `pointer to book`. `&b` type is `pointer to pointer to book`. You probably intended to do `a = b` here.

Comment: `a=&b;` isn't valid C code and will not compile, so that would be why.

Comment: @user3597222: A pointer variable does not contain the structure data; it only contains a "reference" to where the data is. The `malloc(sizeof (book))` allocates memory for the structure data, and returns the pointer (the "reference") to it. You can assign that value to as many pointers as you wish, and they all will refer to the same book data, equally. The `->` operator tells the compiler that the left side is a pointer to a structure, and the right side names the member the expression should evaluate to. Compare to `.`, where the left side refers to the structure, not a pointer to one.

Answer (score 2):

What you do here is storing the address of `b` in `a`. When dereferencing `a` now you get what is stored in `b` which is the **address** of where your book is stored, not the book itself. In fact I think you should get a segmentation fault when trying to access `a->pages` because this memory wasn't even allocated.

So I think what you want to do here is to make `a` a pointer to the same `book` structure as `b` which you can achieve by just doing

```
book *a = b;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this you need to make `a` as pointer to pointer because `b` is pointer.

```
book **a;
a=&b;
```

you can do as below with `a`  using just a pointer.

```
book *a;
a=b;
```

Comment: There is a difference in between "`double` pointer" and "pointer to pointer".

Comment: Is it ok that after doing what you wrote, when I change the value of pages at a, I get it also in b?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with this line:

```
a=&b;
```

is to assign a pointer to `book` to a pointer to pointer to `book`.

Usually, the compiler will emit an error which will look something like this:

```
 error: cannot convert 'book**' to 'book*' in assignment.
```

But it looks like you have directly run it in debug mode. 
So it is good to compile the code, remove all the errors and warnings and then start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to know a pointer is a variable, it is also have the address, you define a pointer variable, if you don't give it to apply for space, the system will automatically give it a space, so, if you want to let two Pointers equal you'll have to define a secondary pointer, then the secondary pointer to the address is another pointer itself.So you should change it like this

```
book **a;  //a is a second level pointer
a=&b;      //Now a is pointing to the address of b itself,Because b has an address
```